# Any advantage of using just string instead of URI uri = new URI(String) while doing resttemplate call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest

please let me know is there any advantage of using just string instead of
URI uri = new URI(String) while doing resttemplate call

Comment: ...beacuse URI makes some  checks on your string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, it validates the string supplied and it throws IllegalArugumentException If the given string violates RFC 2396. So prevalidations would happen beforehand!